# Can a user hide a column in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I've published a dashboard and a few of the users of the dashboard would like to be able to hide columns. All the columns in the dashboard are needed but based on different use cases some users would like to hide columns so that they can focus on what is important to their work. Is this functionality possible for users who will just have access to Tableau via a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get this effect is to put Measure Names on the rows shelf, and also on the Filter Shelf, and then show a filter control for Measure Names to allow the user to choose which measures get displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you're trying to build a **report builder** which allows the user to play around with the dimensions as well as measures and download a crosstab of the table.

As Mr.Alex says for dynamic measures selection you can move measure names to filters shelf.

If you are planning for a more dynamic dashboard which lets the user select dimensions as well, in that case, you can use a parameter to provide a list of options to select from and also create a calculated field which looks something like this:

```
CASE [Dimension.1 ] 
WHEN 'Column 1' THEN [Column 1] 
WHEN 'Column 2' THEN [Column 2] 
WHEN 'Column 3' THEN [Column 3]
WHEN 'Column 4'THEN [Column 4]
WHEN 'Dimension 1' THEN ""
END
```

This calculated field must be dragged to the rows shelf and you're done. 
Add parameter control to the dashboard. Comment if you're stuck anywhere.